# MySQL:- Join two SELECT queries including join and aliases also

Tags: mysql

I have two queries and both are working fine individually, but I want to join both the queries and display the output in a single grid.

**Query1**

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM item_master t1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT item_master_id,
   SUM(received_quantity) AS received_quantity,
   SUM(ordered_quantity)  AS ordered_quantity,
   SUM(unit_cost)  AS unit_cost
FROM material_line_item
GROUP BY item_master_id) t2
ON t1.id = t2.item_master_id
```

In this query1 I am using two tables to fetch records

**Query2**

```
SELECT item_master_id
,SUM(open_quantity) open_quantity
FROM closed_stock
GROUP BY item_master_id
```

And in query2 from a single table

In all the above 3 tables 3 columns are there `received_quantity` `ordered_quantity` and `open_quantity` so I have to show all this 3 quantity columns in a single query by joining this above two queries.

So far what I tried

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM item_master t1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT item_master_id,
   SUM(received_quantity) AS received_quantity,
   SUM(ordered_quantity)  AS ordered_quantity,
   SUM(unit_cost)  AS unit_cost
FROM material_line_item
GROUP BY item_master_id) t2
ON t1.id = t2.item_master_id)

join 

(SELECT item_master_id
,SUM(available_quantity) open_quantity
FROM closed_stock
GROUP BY item_master_id)
```

Comment: Could you please add create table scripts, sample data and expected output?

Comment: @TomV the problem is solved I got the output from the below answer. But thanks anyway for your interest on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to simplify the query without nested levels of subqueries. You already have as simple table (`t1`) joined to a derived table (`t2`). Join them further to the other query2 as a derived table (lets call it `t3` in lack of a better name):

```
SELECT 
    t1.*, 

    t2.received_quantity,
    t2.ordered_quantity,
    t2.unit_cost,

    t3.open_quantity
FROM 
        item_master AS t1
    INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT item_master_id,
           SUM(received_quantity) AS received_quantity,
           SUM(ordered_quantity)  AS ordered_quantity,
           SUM(unit_cost)         AS unit_cost
        FROM material_line_item
        GROUP BY item_master_id
        ) AS t2
    ON t1.id = t2.item_master_id

    INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT item_master_id,
               SUM(open_quantity) AS open_quantity
        FROM closed_stock
        GROUP BY item_master_id
        ) AS t3
    ON t1.id = t3.item_master_id ;
```

If there are items in the `item_master` table that don't appear in one or both the other two tables, you might want to change these `INNER` joins to `LEFT` joins.

Comment: Great :) @ypercube